# WiX toolset: How to execute multiple exe files with MSI package

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exe

I am working on my first MSI builder with WiX. I am hoping that I can receive some help on what I am trying to achieve.

For my app, the user has to have `Visual Studio Code (latest)` and a couple of other applications on the local machine. Therefore, I included `.exe` file in the MSI package like the screenshot below.

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to run those execution files as a part of Microsoft Installer download...?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and WiX toolset to build a Microsoft installer.

I appreciate any comments or resource that I can look into.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a bootstrapper (setup.exe) to properly get them preinstalled along with installing your app's MSI. You can generate a bootstrapper using a [WiX bundle](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/).